# c++: async throw C2752 and C2064

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, asynchronous, throw

I had hard time understanding how to use **async** function.

I don't want to use boost library but just want to run a function asynchronously, so I ask your help:

- How to use **async** to make this code working ?
- Is there any other    way of doing this ?

*Here's a piece of my code:*

```
void KWxAPI::update(bool const no_interact)
{
async(launch::async, &KWxAPI::syncUpdate, no_interact);
}

bool KWxAPI::syncUpdate(bool const nointeract)
{
    //blablabla
}
```

*And here are the errors the build gimme:* [See on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/H2issmL2)

I really hope you'll help me cause I come from Java and C++ is much harder :C

EDIT: I'm using MSVC.

Comment: can you tell which compiler is you are using. are you using boost or standard C++11 library.?

Comment: I'm using MSVC without any special settings as far as I know.

Comment: For info: Op is using VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because you're trying to invoke a pointer to a member function, without passing the object to invoke it on.

`KWxAPI::syncUpdate` needs a `KWxAPI` object to use as it's `this` pointer, but you aren't passing one. Any time you try to invoke a pointer-to-member function, such as this, you need to pass the `this` pointer it should use as the first parameter.

```
std::async(std::launch::async, &KWxAPI::syncUpdate, this, no_interact);
```

Aside from this, you should be aware that `KWxAPI::syncUpdate` will execute in another thread, but your `std::async` statement will block until that thread finishes executing the function.

This is because `std::async` returns an `std::future` object, which is destructed at the end of your `std::async` statement, because you aren't storing it anywhere. In it's destructor, it blocks until execution has completed.